# Zip two lists of strings to use as keys in dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, zip

I have a text file with about thirty lines of this:

```
F2(g)+2e–|2F–(aq)|+2.87
Co3+(aq)+e–|Co2+(aq)|+1.82
```

I've split the lines at '|' to create three separate lists, but I want to merge the lists `left` and `right` and use the zipped list as key in a dictionary, with the third list as values. This is my current code:

```
infile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
data = {}

for line in lines[1:]:
    left, right, value = line.rstrip('\n').split('|')
    z = [str(x[0]) + x[1] for x in zip(left, right)] 
    data[z]=value
```

This does not work. When I try to zip `left` and `right` to `z`, I get a result like this:

```
['F2', '2F', '(–', 'g(', ')a', '+q', '2)']
['CC', 'oo', '32', '++', '((', 'aa', 'qq', '))']
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is this output:

```
{
    'F2(g)+2e– 2F–(aq)': '+2.87',
    'Co3+(aq)+e– Co2+(aq)': '+1.82'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have lists, you have strings, as you are processing a single line from your input file at a time. Your mistake then is to use `zip()` on the `left` and `right` strings. You don't want to pair up the characters of the two strings, you just want to *concatenate* the strings, with a space in between.

You could use `+`, or `' '.join()`, or for just two values, use string formatting:

```
for line in lines[1:]:
    left, right, value = line.rstrip('\n').split('|')
    z = f'{left} {right}'
    data[z] = value
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! This was driving me crazy, and I didn't know where the problem was. Such an easy solution too. You saved my weekend.